# Why is `evalf` not working?

Tags: maple

Why is `evalf` not changing $\pi$ and $e$ to floating point in the following:

`h := proc (x) options operator, arrow; exp(x)*cos(x) end proc`

`Tay := taylor(h(x), x = (1/6)*pi, 2)`

`P2 := convert(Tay, polynom)`

`evalf(P2(.5))`

The output is`(exp((1/6)*Pi))(.5)*(cos((1/6)*Pi))(.5)+(-1.*(exp((1/6)*Pi))(.5)*(sin((1/6)*Pi))(.5)+(exp((1/6)*Pi))(.5)*(cos((1/6)*Pi))(.5))*(x(.5)-.1666666667*Pi(.5))`. For my calculation, I need $\pi$  and $e$ to be approximations.

Comment: Did you try using placeholder variables like `mypi=3.14159...` and `mye=2.71828...`?

Comment: I did not, but `evalf(pi)` and `evalf(exp(1))` usually evaluate to floating point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Maple, Pi is $\pi$, but pi is just a variable.

Also, seeing the result, I think you shouldn't do "evalf(P2(0.5))", but "evalf(subs(x=0.5,P2))".

Answer (score 2):

You should use the  capital letter for 'Pi-

Tay := taylor(h(x), x = (1/6) *Pi, 2);

It works.